# Command Prompt 5sec delay before opening. Now it won’t open at all

Tags: windows, command-line

`cmd.exe` and `command.com` doesn't open instantly - Instead I get a 5 second delay upon running them(either from clicking the files, or running them from 'run'). I tried Googling it, but alas. Finally I just accepted it.

So now I've started coding some basic stuff with MS Visual Studio and now the command prompt won't even open after compiling. Also, if I have MS Visual Studio running, I cannot run command prompt in any way. It just queues up as a process in the taskmgr.

Anyone got any relevant info/tips/fixes? Not only am I not able to code, but now I can't even do basic stuff in my command prompt like ping or tracert.

Comment: Here's a prntscrn of my taskmgr.

http://bildr.no/view/684709

Comment: What exactly is "MS Visual"?

Comment: Microsoft Visual. In this case Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Comment: When you say "MS Visual running, I cannot run command prompt in any way" do you mean "When I'm debugging and are stopped on a breakpoint?"

Comment: Crosspost of http://superuser.com/questions/162699/command-prompt-5sec-delay-before-opening-now-it-wont-open-at-all

Answer (score 2):

You could try running another Sysinternals tool: [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). That will tell you about file and registry access (you will probably want to use filtering on the output, to reduce clutter).

Also have a look at [this page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433) which describes AutoRun settings for cmd.exe in the registry.

Possibly the following Registry keys have some commands which are being run when you start the command prompt:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

or

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist thing that I would do is run [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) check process tree and handles form cmd.exe . Kill unusual things from the process tree one by one and see what happens ;) (make sure you don't have any unsaved and important data open just in case you will kill some innocent program ;)

Comment: Well I'm only running like 7 processes(explorer.exe), and I see nothing malicious in process explorer. So yeah ;> No memory jam or CPU problems iether. My comp is running just fine, it's just the command prompt that is 'broken' :(